# Orthogonal vectors proof (using distance)

Tags: calculus

The exercise says.-

Suppose $x,y$ are nonzero vectors in $\Bbb R ^n$. Prove that they are orthogonal if and only if $||x+cy|| \ge ||x||$ for any $c \in \Bbb R$.

A tool may be that $||x+y||^2=||x||^2+||y||^2$ if they are orthogonal; but I don’t know how to prove that they satisfy that condition only if they are orthogonal. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are orthogonal, then
$$|x+cy|=\sqrt{|x|^2+c^2|y|^2}\ge|x|$$

If for all $c$,
$$|x+cy|^2=|y|^2c^2+2cx\cdot y+|x|^2\ge|x|^2$$

It implies
$$|y|^2c^2+2 x\cdot y c \ge 0$$

So the discriminant of the above quadratic must be non-positive

$$4(x\cdot y)^2 \le 0$$

But the LHS is always non-negative, so we conclude that

$$x\cdot y=0$$

Comment: Thanks! Could I prove it for |x+ry| the same way if I define r=-c? Will it be valid?

Comment: Plus or minus doesn't matter. Anyway, I've edited my answer.

Comment: Could you explain to me why the discriminant is always <= 0 if the equation is positive?

Comment: Because with a positive discriminant, the quadratic will have two distinct roots, between which its value will be negative.